# Google Sheets conditional formatting multiple columns based on value relative to 1 column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a reference column of values (column A & B) and then all subsequent pairs of columns that get added to sheet, I want to highlight their value in relation to those two. So column C values, if higher than relative Column A value, mark green and highlight in red if lower. Same for Column D values, relative to Column B values. Ideally, I want 4 rules:

1. If Column C, E, G, I, K, M > column A, mark each cell green
2. If Column C, E, G, I, K, M < column A, mark each cell red
3. If Column D, F, H, J, L, N > column B, mark each cell green
4. If Column D, F, H, J, L, N < column B, mark each cell red

[image]

Right now, I can add a formula for each column, but that's cumbersome as I may end up with hundreds of columns as time goes on.

Comment: Hundreds of columns sounds like it might be better to create the formatting rule via a script.